# Error connecting to database on other PC

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I created a database (`*.mdf` file) with SQL Server Express in Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop. My operating system is Windows 8 Pro 64-bit.

I add this database in my application according to tutorial of this website:
http://homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s12p5.html

I follow exactly same procedure for my application.

When I run my application in Visual Studio by pressing F5 button it works perfectly (on my PC). But when I publish it and try to run it on another machine, then my database connection doesn't work. My application is not able to connect to database on any PC rather than mine.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Please show your connection string

Answer (score 0):

You must change your Connection String according to the other PC 's settings.
eg: Server,PC

Answer (score 0):

Try this connection string.

```
Driver={SQL Native Client};Server=[IP of the Server]\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=[path]\*.mdf; Database=dbname;Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

You can refer [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005/)

Answer (score 0):

Open Application.exe.config and change your connection string according to that machine. For example

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="StoreConnectionString"
      connectionString="Data Source=PCName\InstanceName;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=False;"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```